ssh_host_rsa key with two sshd configurations
I have a system on which passwordless SSH and SFTP has been working for years, no issues. I now have an important application that needs SFTP, but the hitch is that this application does not currently support key authentication.
I do not want to allow password authentication on the main SSH service. And I want the new service to only allow specific users.
So I have created a group (sftppwd) which has two users within it (both in the group sftppwd), and created the users.  I copied the /etc/ssh/sshd_config to /etc/ssh/sshd8022_config, and made the following changes:
diff sshd*_config
5c5
< Port 8022
---
> Port 22
23c23
< SyslogFacility LOCAL0
---
> SyslogFacility AUTH
28c28
< PermitRootLogin no
---
> PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
31,32c31,32
< #RSAAuthentication no
< PubkeyAuthentication no
---
> #RSAAuthentication yes
> PubkeyAuthentication yes
35,37d34
< 
< AllowGroups sftppwd
< 
92c89
< UsePAM no
---
> UsePAM yes
96c93,94
<     ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /%u
---
>     ForceCommand internal-sftp

I copied the sshd.service to a new ssh8022.service, and made a couple of changes there:
diff sshd.service ssh8022.service
10c10
< ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
---
> ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS -f /etc/ssh/sshd8022_config
22c22
< Alias=sshd.service
---
> Alias=ssh8022.service

And started the service. When I try to log in to the new service, the following error appears in /var/log/auth.log:
Apr  6 20:46:03 web sshd[529209]: error: Public key for /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key does not match private key

This error does not occur with the port 22 configuration, only with the 8022 config.  Both are configured to use the same key (which I would expect, and I would also expect that to work) but there's apparently something amiss here.
Do you have any idea what step I may have missed, or how I can get around this error?  Do I need to create a new keypair?  If so, do I need to also do DSA and ECDSA?
The sshd config files for both configurations contain this:
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

EDIT: This is the Match group content in both configurations at present:
Match group sftppwd
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    ChrootDirectory /sftp-files
    PermitTunnel no
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no

Both sshd processes are running under root, so should have no permissions problems.  And anyway, the permissions look like I would expect.
ls -l /etc/ssh/s*key*
-rw------- 1 root root 1393 Nov  1  2022 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  609 Nov  1  2022 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw------- 1 root root  513 Nov  1  2022 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  181 Nov  1  2022 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw------- 1 root root  411 Nov  1  2022 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  101 Nov  1  2022 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw------- 1 root root 2602 Nov  1  2022 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  403 Nov 22  2022 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub

> ps -ef|grep sshd
root      528031       1  0 Apr06 ?        00:00:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D -f /etc/ssh/sshd8022_config [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
root      528139       1  0 Apr06 ?        00:00:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
root      545137  528139  0 07:21 ?        00:00:00 sshd: delovelady [priv]
delovel+  545219  545137  0 07:21 ?        00:00:00 sshd: delovelady@pts/1

EDIT 9-Apr, Shanghai
I'm not really sure what I'm dealing with here.  I have moved the Match Group to hear the top of the sshd8022_config file, followed by a Match all line.  I have set LogLevel DEBUG3 on this service, and stopped and restarted it.  I've verified with netstat -tulpn and ps -fp that this service is running on port 8022 with this configuration file.  And yet, when this sequence occurs:
ssh -p 8022 delovelady@localhost
delovelady@localhost's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
delovelady@localhost's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
delovelady@localhost's password: 
delovelady@localhost: Permission denied ().
root@web:/etc/ssh   04/08 22:17:18
> tail /var/log/auth.log

I do not see any recent activity at all in the auth.log file.  These are all more then five mnutes old
Apr  8 22:16:02 web CRON[606095]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user **masked**
Apr  8 22:16:09 web CRON[606096]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user fm-agent
Apr  8 22:17:01 web CRON[606123]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user fm-agent(uid=996) by (uid=0)
Apr  8 22:17:01 web CRON[606122]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Apr  8 22:17:01 web CRON[606121]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user **masked**(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Apr  8 22:17:01 web CRON[606122]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr  8 22:17:01 web CRON[606121]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user **masked**
Apr  8 22:17:10 web CRON[606123]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user fm-agent
Apr  8 22:17:25 web CRON[606054]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user **masked**

One of my ongoing problems with UBUNTU is that logging seems to be an increasingly difficult task (surpassed only by the difficulty of getting at some of those logs).  Unless/until I can get useful information from the logs, I am left with a mysterious black box.  Any help there?

I don't know if it has anything to do with the problem, but note that changing #RSAAuthentication yes to #RSAAuthentication no has no effect because the line is commented out anyway. I'm bringing this to your attention in case you really wanted to change this exact setting.

Thanks, yes I did realize that and thought to remove the line from the question, but decided to leave it.  Agreed, should have no effect

Hostkeys aside, is there actually a need for two services? Wouldn't it have been enough to allow password auth on the main service for that specific group only?

Yep, Match section with PasswordAuthentication might do. As for the problem I would check file permissions and the uid and gid of respective sshd/sftp processes, the message may as well mean that it cannot read one of the files.

@u1686_grawity I did try to add PasswordAuthentication yes to the Match group setting.  No joy; I figured the overall PasswordAuthentication no may have overridden.  Besides, I want to be able to allow this capability only during certain hours, by starting and stopping the service.  I don't know a good way to do that with only one service.

@Tomek I just tried this again (allowing Password Authentication in the port 22 sshd_config file).  The error I get when someone tries to lo in with password surprised me: "Unable to negotiate with 212.102.50.217 port 61154: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]"  In any case, it's not doing what I want.

The error provided tells where the issue is at: Public key for /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key does not match private key Why it believes there's a mismatch between the private and public key of ssh_host_rsa_key is more the over-arching question - since it's not normal for two SSH servers to use the same key at the same time (it's non-standard usage - is it even supported? it's also bad security practice), it would seem to point to that as the issue. To rule out, generate separate host keys for the sshd8022_config, updating in the config and restarting that server, and see if that resolves

@Dennis: I've used that inside Match groups in the past; the "no matching host key type" error you're getting is unrelated to that. Host keys are checked well before user auth takes place.

sshd is pretty particular about ordering: For each keyword, the first obtained value will be used.. This means you cannot use PasswordAuthentication before your Match section. Have your specific Match first and after that specify catch-all Match section to force whatever you need for PasswordAuthentication.

One thing which catches the eye is the modification date of the RSA public key file, which is 3 weeks after all other key files. Are you sure it hasn't been accidentally corrupted? And are you absolutely sure that the error message comes from only one of the services? What if you force RSA host key for the supposedly correct service?

@Tomek - thanks for your replies.  Yes, you were right on two counts about the public key.  Recreating the public key rom the private made that error go away; and the error was also issued by the port 22 service.  Please see my most recent update of the question.  I'm lost.

@Tomek: for sshd (not ssh) it does work correctly to set a given option before all Match blocks (called 'global') and also in Match block(s). If you set it more than once in the global portion only the first is used, and if you set it more than once in satisfied Match blocks only the first of those is used.
